# Elasticsearch - perform multi-field max aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, elk

I have an index that contains events from different sources, therefore, I have two different names for the same field, "**accounting_date**" and "**dt_comptable**", and I need to query and get the max of the two field's values,
The following query worked for me for one single field:

```
GET indexXX/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "latest_accounting_date": {
      "max": {
        "field": "dt_comptable"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to include the other field "**accounting_date**".

Comment: Do you need to get the max of the two fields per document id?

Comment: @AssaelAzran no, I need the max date between all docs but using the two fields, cause each doc has one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html#_script_7)... Instead of specifying a field you can specify a script that will retrieve either field, whichever is present, but the `max` aggregation will be able to work on both of them:

```
GET indexXX/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "latest_accounting_date": {
      "max": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['dt_comptable'].size() > 0 ? doc['dt_comptable'].value : doc['accounting_date'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, you gave me a good lead, I updated your answer cuz I have some docs without values, it works fine but I can no longer get the value as string, instead I get result just as Long type:
"aggregations" : {
    "latest_accounting_date" : {
      "value" : 1.5943392E12
    }
  }

Comment: It must have been the same before, the max aggregation returns you the long value of the most recent date, never a string. That long value is the number of milliseconds since the epoch, so it's easy to transform it back to a date string if you need.

Comment: What I meant by string is the "value_as_string" that I get when using simple max with field :  "aggregations" : {
    "latest_accounting_date" : {
      "value" : 1.5943392E12,
      "value_as_string" : "2020-07-10"
    }
  }
But as you said I can convert the long value to date anyway, so thank you very much